# Obtener las key de un map para ingresar en spinner

Tags: java, android-studio

Quiero obtener las claves de un map o hasmap para colocar en un spinner, pero he probado infinidad de cosas y no me funciona ninguna, y las que me funcionan salen mal o todas las claves juntas y repetidas.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ShopsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
List<String> categories;

private static Map<String, String[]> categoria;
static {
    categoria=new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    categoria.put("Alimentacion", new String[] {"Carnes", "Pescados", "Frutas", "Verduras","Panaderia", "Bolleria"});
    categoria.put("Limpieza", new String[]{"Desinfectantes","Jabones"});
    categoria.put("Perfumeria",new String[]{"Perfumes","Cosmetica"});
    categoria.put("Ropa", new String[]{"Pantalones","Camisas"});
    categoria.put("Farmacia", new String[]{"Cremas", "Medicinas"});
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shops);

    Spinner spinnerCategoria=findViewById(R.id.spinner_categoria);
    Spinner spinnerSubCategoria=findViewById(R.id.spinner_subcategoria);

    ;
    /*for(String categoria:categoria.keySet().toArray().toString()){
        categories.add(categoria);
    }*/

    ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categories);
    spinnerCategoria.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

}
```

}

Al mismo tiempo si alguien sabrai como hacer el menu spinner con los submenus tambien en spinner que diga.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el constructor de `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)` pasandole el `keySet()` del map `categoria`.

Solo tendrias que añadir esta linea:

`categories = new ArrayList<>(categoria.keySet());`

Answer (score 0):

El método keySet() devuelve todas las keys, basta con recorrerlas:

```
for (String key : categoria.keySet()) {
    // Mostramos cada key que vamos encontrando
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

Comment: No, si las keys consigo recorrerlas, el problema viene en el ArrayÄdapter para el spinnerCategoria que no funciona.